# How to ensure that UDP socket is closed?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, datagram

I have a Client Server application. The client sends commands to server and receives the data on a UDP socket channel.
Each time the socket file is created with a different id.
I am executing the command 10000 times using a script and I get `EBADF`.
The problem I am suspecting is that the `close()` does not closes the socket descriptor immediately.
I have read about SO_LINGER options but I think it works for TCP socket.

Is there any way to ensure that `close()` closes the socket descriptor.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you continually opening and closing UDP sockets at all? Why not keep one open for the life of the program?

Comment: This is already done in the existing code. I cannot change it and open it for a lifetime.

Comment: You might like to show us the code in question.

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem here is that you probably aren't checking the result of *creating* the socket in the first place, or you're closing the socket and then reusing it, or corrupting the handle value, so you are encountering EBADF later on. EBADF is the result of a prior programming error. Not a failure to close. Find out what the actual error is. Don't guess.

Comment: I am getting success in creation and bind on socket, but the problem still exists.

Comment: *What* problem? EBADF when doing *what?* This sounds like just a bug in your code: losing the value of an FD somewhere, or closing it and still using it. There's no evidence here of a descriptor leak or non-close problem.

Comment: I am getting EBADF in sendto() API. The socket() and fcntl() give me a success..

Comment: So you are calling sendto() on a socket that has already been closed, or with an invalid handle such as -1.

Comment: I create a socket using socket() and then call fcntl() with O_NONBLOCK flag. Both these call are a success.I am then calling sendto() which gives me EBADF.

Comment: @Marik You don't seem to be listening. I don't know why you're even posting here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30316/discussion-between-manik-sidana-and-ejp)

Comment: Certainly not. I've wasted enough time on this already. You need to go and do some work.

Comment: @Manik I'll give you a hint: run your program under strace and you'll immediately find your bug. Either sendto is being called with a completely bogus file descriptor (like -1) or you closed the fd earlier, in which case the trace will make it obvious where you went wrong.

Comment: @Nicholas: Thanks for the idea.. I figured out the problem. The issue was that the same socket descriptor was getting closed twice - once by close_socket() function of my class and once by the destructor.

Comment: @EJP: That was an arrogant reply.